# How do I include maven environment variables in eclipse to war file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have environment variables in my application.properties like this `spring.mail.username=${username}`

The `${username}` is declare in eclipse environment variable. When I build maven package and install, then deploy it to tcServer. The TC Server does not know `${username}`. Another word, the environment variables do not include in the war file during build.

How do I get the environment variable in eclipse to include in war file for deployment?

Comment: You wish to have the user who built the system ? Not the user who executes it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have a build-time variable replaced, I would suggest you to use maven filtering:

**Have an environment variable (not an eclipse one):**

```
export username=user3184890
```

Then, in your pom.xml, **activate maven filtering** on resources (assuming your application.properties is in `src/main/resources`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
```

Also, **change your application.properties** to this:

```
spring.mail.username=${env.username}
```

or

```
spring.mail.username=@env.username@
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven filtering as described in alexbt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41660885/3304238), is the right approach for including values defined elsewhere. His example touches on including an operating system environment variable. You can extend this to Maven properties also. For example,

```
<project ...>
   <properties>
      <spring.mailuser>bob@mycompany.com</spring.mailuser>
   </properties>
   ...
   <build>
      ...
   </build>
</project>
```

defines a Maven properties whose value is retrieved by `${spring.mailuser}` and can be used as part
of other Maven configurations or injected as content via Maven filtering. Given this, changing
`applicable.properties` as follows

```
 spring.mail.username=${spring.mailuser}
```

will inject the value of the property at build time.